# What's wrong with my code? Histograms in R with percentage as .png

Tags: r, plot, histogram

StackOverflow already helped me very much, but I have trouble putting everything together.

I want to automatically generate histograms from data stored in txt files. Each file contains one data column.

This is original code I wrote and it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

#for all .txt files in a directory
for(i in 1:length(list.files(pattern="*.txt"))) 
{
#reading data
histo = read.table(list.files(pattern="*.txt")[i])

#cutting off ".txt"
name = list.files(pattern="*.txt")[i]
name = strsplit(name, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
name = name[1]

png(name)

hist(
    main = paste("Histogram dla probki" , name),
    histo$V1, 
    breaks = 10,
    freq = FALSE,

    #looks
    col = "gray",
    tck = -0.015,

    #labels
    xlab = "srednica [um]",
    ylab = "gestosc"
)


box()
dev.off()
}
```

This is how it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYprl.png

I want to change y axis to percentages and add label for each column, like in this one:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/histogram_anno_hist_ods.png

I changed my code, implementing what I found on SO and other sites, I corrected any errors I encountered. When I run the script it doesn't return any errors and it seems it works. However, it doesn't generate any pictures as well.

New code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

for(i in 1:length(list.files(pattern="*.txt"))) 
{
#reading data
histo = read.table(list.files(pattern="*.txt")[i])

#cutting off ".txt"
name = list.files(pattern="*.txt")[i]
name = strsplit(name, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
name = name[1]

histPercent <- function(histo) 
    {
    png(name)
    h <- hist(histo$V1, plot = FALSE)
    h$density <- with(h, 100*density*diff(breaks)[1])
    labs <- paste(round(h$density), "%", sep="")
    plot(h,
        main = paste("Histogram dla próbki " , name),
        histo$V1, 
        breaks = 10,
        freq = FALSE,

        #looks
        col = "green",
        tck = -0.015,

        labels = labs,
        xlab = "średnica [um]",
        ylab = "udział procentowy"
        )
    dev.off()
    }

#box()

}
```

What's wrong? I also tried with png() and dev.off() outside the function.

Comment: Are you calling the histPercent function anywhere in your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `histPercent` is not correctly being put, so you are not getting any output. Try the below code...

**R Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

#for all .txt files in a directory
for(i in 1:length(list.files(pattern="*.txt"))) 
{
  #reading data
  histo = read.table(list.files(pattern="*.txt")[i])

  #cutting off ".txt"
  name = list.files(pattern="*.txt")[i]
  name = strsplit(name, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
  name = name[1]

  png(name)      
  h = hist(histo$V1)
  h$density = h$counts/sum(h$counts)*100
  labs <- paste(round(h$density), "%", sep="")
  plot(h,main = paste("Histogram dla próbki", name), freq = F, labels =     labs, histo$V1,breaks =10, col = "lightgreen", tck = -0.015, xlab = "srednica     [um]", ylab = "udział procentowy")

  box()
  dev.off()
}
```

**Chart output:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I have something wrong with those green patterns and I received such message for each of the histograms
  
  
`Warning in title(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
  "breaks" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in axis(1, ...) : "breaks" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in axis(2, ...) : "breaks" is not a graphical parameter"`
  
  
Moving "breaks" from `plot()` to `hist()` fixed this issue.  
I still need to fiddle with these patterns and general look of the histograms, but these are minor issues. Thanks again!